# What is the expectation of $B_s^2B_t^2$ where $B_t$ is a standard Brownian motion?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expected-value, brownian-motion

I am tring to find the variance of the integral $I=\int_0^T B_t^2 dt$.

I have found that $\mathbb{E}[I] = \int_0^T \mathbb{E}[B_t^2] dt = \frac{T^2}{2}$.

Since $\mathbb{E}[I^2] = \mathbb{E}[\int_0^T \int_0^T B_t^2 B_s^2 \ dt\ ds] = \int_0^T \int_0^T \mathbb{E}[B_t^2 B_s^2] \ dt \ ds$, I want to know the value of $\mathbb{E}\left[B_t^2 B_s^2\right]$.

Comment: Hint : $B_t^2B_s^2 = (B_s + (B_{t} - B_s))^2B_s^2 = B_s^4 + 2B_s^3(B_t - B_s) + B_s^2(B_t-B_s)^2$ and use independence and stationarity of increments , along with $B_s \sim N(0,s)$.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thanks! I got it. It is a little bit hard to think up this decomposition.

Comment: Yes, you need to spend some time with Brownian motion. This idea extends. Also, I am sure you have justified it, but taking the expectation $\mathbb E$ inside the integral $\int_0^t B_t^2 dt$ : I just want to confirm you know why we can do it.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thanks for the reminder. By Fubini and some regulatiry checks, we can switch the integral sign.

Comment: @FLB Precisely, that's what I was looking for, actually the integrand is non-negative so you can apply Fubini directly. +1 to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $s<t$ we have $EB_t^{2}B_s^{2}=E((B_t-B_s)+B_s)^{2}B_s^{2}=E((B_t-B_s))^{2}B_s^{2}+EB_s^{4}$ since $E((B_t-B_s)B_s)B_s^{2}E((B_t-B_s)) EB_s^{3}=0$. So $EB_t^{2}B_s^{2}=E((B_t-B_s))^{2}EB_s^{2}+EB_s^{4}=(t-s) s+EB_s^{4}$. $EB_s^{4}=s^{2}m_4$ where $m_4$ is the 4th moment of the standard normal distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach. Suppose we want to compute
$$
\mathbb{E}[B_{t_1}B_{t_2}\ldots B_{t_n}].
$$
This is really a moment of the random vector $(B_{t_1},\ldots,B_{t_n})$, so we attempt to compute the characteristic function
$$
\varphi(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)=\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda_1B_{t_1}+\ldots+\lambda_n B_{t_n})].
$$
We want to somehow use independence of increments. WLOG assume $t_1\geq ...\geq t_n$. I believe the following is analogous to the trick that the comments and previous answer used:
\begin{align}
\varphi(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n) &= \mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda_1(B_{t_1}-B_{t_2})+(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)B_{t_2}\ldots+\lambda_n B_{t_n})]\\
&=\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda_1(B_{t_1}-B_{t_2})+(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)(B_{t_2}-B_{t_3})+(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3)B_{t_3}+\ldots+\lambda_n B_{t_n})]\\
&=\ldots\\
&=\mathbb{E}\bigg[\exp\!\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n(\lambda_1+\ldots+\lambda_i)(B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i+1}})\bigg)\bigg]\\
&=\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}\big[\!\exp\!\big((\lambda_1+\ldots+\lambda_i)(B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i+1}})\big)\big].
\end{align}
In going to the second-to-last last line, I have additionally defined $t_{n+1}=0$ so that $B_{t_{n+1}}=0$. The last line follows by independence of increments. Since $B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i+1}}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,t_i-t_{i+1})$, we have
\begin{align}
\varphi(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n) &= \prod_{i=1}^n\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{(\lambda_1+\ldots+\lambda_i)x}\mathcal{N}(0,t_i-t_{i+1})\,\mathrm{d}x = \prod_{i=1}^n e^{\frac{1}{2}(\lambda_1+\ldots+\lambda_i)^2(t_i-t_{i+1})}\\
&=\exp\!\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n(\lambda_1+\ldots+\lambda_i)^2(t_i-t_{i+1})\bigg).
\end{align}
In case $t_i - t_{i+1}=0$ for some $i$, it is obvious that this result still holds since then $B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i+1}}=0\sim\delta_0$. Anyway, we can now differentiate this:
$$
\mathbb{E}[B_{t_1}B_{t_2}\ldots B_{t_n}] = \frac{\partial^n}{\partial \lambda_1\ldots\partial\lambda_n}\bigg\vert_{\lambda = 0}\varphi(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n).
$$
In your case ($s\geq t$):
$$
\mathbb{E}[B_s^2 B_t^2] = \frac{\partial^4}{\partial \lambda_1\partial\lambda_2\partial\lambda_3\partial\lambda_4}\bigg\vert_{\lambda = 0}e^{\frac{1}{2}(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)^2(s-t)+\frac{1}{2}(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3+\lambda_4)^2t}.
$$
By Taylor expansion this equals the coefficient of $\lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3\lambda_4$ in the polynomial
$$
\frac{1}{8}\big((\lambda_1+\lambda_2)^2(s-t)+(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3+\lambda_4)^2t\big)^2.
$$
This comes out to
$$
\mathbb{E}[B_s^2 B_t^2] = (s-t)t + 3t^2,
$$
which is the same as Kavi Rama Murthy's result. Alternatively, and perhaps a bit more quickly, one could also proceed via
$$
\mathbb{E}[B_s^2 B_t^2]=\frac{\partial^4}{\partial\lambda_1^2\partial\lambda_2^2}\bigg\vert_{\lambda=0}\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda_1 B_s+\lambda_2 B_t)] = \frac{\partial^4}{\partial\lambda_1^2\partial\lambda_2^2}\bigg\vert_{\lambda=0} e^{\frac{1}{2}\lambda_1^2 (s-t) + \frac{1}{2}(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)^2 t}.
$$